# Calculating minimal unknown coefficients of a sum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, summation, coefficients

I have a problem, where I have to find the minimum of a function with a sum in it (coefficients are unknown):

```
psi[x_] := 1 + a*x + b*x^2 + c*x^3 + d*x^4 + ...
```

Obviously i can just input

```
NMinimize[expectation[psi], {a, b, c, d,...}]
```

(where "expectation" is just a function) and i get a minimum value. Now, how do i generalize it for n coefficients in the sum? Is this possible (maybe somehow with arrays/lists)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. Please edit your question and include all relevant and complete information, together with ``expectation``. Furthermore, check [`Minimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html) for a symbolic minimization.

Comment: You will get many local minima, at least one for half the roots of `D[psi[x],x] `. Probably is best to separate the problem into parts. Like finding the minimum for `expectation` and the roots for `psi`.

Comment: Start with: `n = 4;
fun[x_] = 
 Array[Subscript[a, #] &, n, 0] . Table[x^i, {i, 0, n - 1}] /. 
  Subscript[a, 0] -> 1`